# How to filter by NaN in string column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas 0.18. I have loaded a dataframe from CSV using `pd.read_csv()`, and it looks as thought the empty cells in CSV have loaded as `NaN` in the dataframe.

Now I want to find the number of rows with an empty value in a particular column, but I'm struggling.

This is my dataframe:

```
      ods         id provider
0  A86016        NaN     emis
1  L81042     463061      NaN
2  C84013        NaN      tpp
3  G82228     462941     emis
4  C81083        NaN      tpp
```

This is what I get from a `df.describe()`:

```
           ods         id provider
count     9897       7186     9022
unique    8066        192        4
top     N83028     463090     emis
freq         7        169     4860
```

I want to get all the rows where `provider` was empty in the CSV. This is what I've tried:

```
>>> print len(df[df.provider == 'NaN'])
0
>>> print len(df[df.provider == np.nan])
0
```

I can see that there are some `NaN` values in there (e.g. row 1) so what gives?

Also, why does pandas convert empty values in string columns like `provider` to `NaN` - wouldn't it make more sense to convert them to an empty string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) for comparing `NaN`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ods': {0: 'A86016', 1: 'L81042', 2: 'C84013', 3: 'G82228', 4: 'C81083'}, 
                   'id': {0: np.nan, 1: 463061.0, 2: np.nan, 3: 462941.0, 4: np.nan}, 
                   'provider': {0: 'emis', 1: np.nan, 2: 'tpp', 3: 'emis', 4: 'tpp'}})

print df
         id     ods provider
0       NaN  A86016     emis
1  463061.0  L81042      NaN
2       NaN  C84013      tpp
3  462941.0  G82228     emis
4       NaN  C81083      tpp

print (df[df.provider.isnull()])

      ods        id provider
1  L81042  463061.0      NaN

print len(df[df.provider.isnull()])
1
```

If you need convert `NaN` to `` use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df.provider.fillna('', inplace=True)
print df
         id     ods provider
0       NaN  A86016     emis
1  463061.0  L81042         
2       NaN  C84013      tpp
3  462941.0  G82228     emis
4       NaN  C81083      tpp
```

[Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#values-considered-missing):

> **Warning**
>
> One has to be mindful that in python (and numpy), the nan's don’t compare equal, but None's do. Note that Pandas/numpy uses the fact that np.nan != np.nan, and treats None like np.nan.

```
In [11]: None == None
Out[11]: True

In [12]: np.nan == np.nan
Out[12]: False
```

> So as compared to above, a scalar equality comparison versus a None/np.nan doesn’t provide useful information.

```
In [13]: df2['one'] == np.nan
Out[13]: 
a    False
b    False
c    False
d    False
e    False
f    False
g    False
h    False
Name: one, dtype: bool
```

But if `nan` is string:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ods': {0: 'A86016', 1: 'L81042', 2: 'C84013', 3: 'G82228', 4: 'C81083'}, 
                   'id': {0: np.nan, 1: 463061.0, 2: np.nan, 3: 462941.0, 4: np.nan}, 
                   'provider': {0: 'emis', 1: 'nan', 2: 'tpp', 3: 'emis', 4: 'tpp'}})

print df
      ods        id provider
0  A86016       NaN     emis
1  L81042  463061.0      nan
2  C84013       NaN      tpp
3  G82228  462941.0     emis
4  C81083       NaN      tpp


print (df[df.provider == 'nan'])
      ods        id provider
1  L81042  463061.0      nan
```

> do you know why pandas imports empty strings as NaN rather than empty strings?

See [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table) (bold by me):

> na_values : *str*, *list-like* or *dict*, default *None*
>
> Additional strings to recognize as NA/NaN. If dict passed, specific per-column NA values. By default the following values are interpreted as NaN: '-1.#IND', '1.#QNAN', '1.#IND', '-1.#QNAN', '#N/A N/A', '#N/A', 'N/A', 'NA', '#NA', 'NULL', 'NaN', '-NaN', 'nan', '-nan', **''**.

Comment: Thanks! Just one more question, do you know why pandas imports empty strings as `NaN` rather than empty strings?

Answer (score 2):

You can first store the na values, and then drop all the rest:

```
without_na = df['provider'].dropna()
df[~df.index.isin(without_na.index)]
```